# Replace string recursively using sed

Tags: bash, shell, recursion, sed

I have a file with below string :

`||||||`

I want to replace every occurrence of `||` with `|""|` so I used

`sed 's/||/|\"\"|/g' temp2.csv`

but I got the output as :

`|""||""||""|` instead of `|""|""|""|""|""|`

I found that sed is not doing the replacement recursively, how can i make sed to do the replacement recursively so it moves over to the next line only when the previous line have no occurrences of `||`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed does not support lookahead or lookbehind, but in your case you can just make a second pass:

```
<temp2.csv sed 's/||/|\"\"|/g' | sed 's/||/|\"\"|/g'
```

Answer (score 5):

the most straight forward way would be call the sed substitution twice. but I think this sed one-liner may be better, because it works if you say, I want to recursively replace `|||..{n}..|` into `|""|""|...{n}..|""|`

```
sed ':a s/||/|""|/g; t a' file
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  cat f
||||||

kent$  sed ':a s/||/|""|/g; t a' f
|""|""|""|""|""|
```

Comment: Could you please explain what does `:a` and `t a` do? Can it be used for anything more complex than `s///`?

Answer (score -2):

Using `awk` you can do this:

```
#echo '||||||' | awk '{gsub(/\|\|/,"|\"\"|")}1'
|""||""||""|
```

Comment: The result is not same as OP's expectation. check the question twice pls.